# Reference to figure and table numbers with Pandoc

Tags: markdown, pandoc, restructuredtext, cross-reference

I'm trying to make a document with `Markdown`/`restructuredText` which will be converted with `pandoc` to PDF using `xelatex`.

I would like to return reference to figure and tables numbers in the text body.

In both Markdown and reSt markup languages, the cross reference return a link to the figure but not the figure number.

for example `[the figure](#myfig)` with markdown or `myfig_` with reST links to the figure but don't automaticly update the figure number.

**Is it possible with Markdown or ReST markup languages to refer to figure and tables number?**

Comment: I can't figure out what you want, so I'll just toss out what I think you mean with a link to possibly relevant docs: http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/roles.html#cross-referencing-figures-by-figure-number

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I suggest using the [pandoc-crossref filter](https://github.com/lierdakil/pandoc-crossref) with pandoc.
The [demo](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/lierdakil/pandoc-crossref/master/docs/demo/demo.md) gives you a good idea of the syntax.  You invoke it by calling pandoc with `--filter pandoc-crossref`.

Answer (score 3):

The [pandoc-fignos](https://github.com/tomduck/pandoc-fignos) and [pandoc-tablenos](https://github.com/tomduck/pandoc-tablenos) filters from the [pandoc-xnos](https://github.com/tomduck/pandoc-xnos) filters suite are good choices for cross-referencing in markdown with pandoc.

To mark a figure for numbering, add an identifier to its attributes:

```
![Caption.](image.png){#fig:id}
```

To reference the figure, use `@fig:id`.

Similarly, to mark a table for numbering, add an identifier to its attributes:

```
A B
- -
0 1

Table: Caption. {#tbl:id}
```

To reference the table, use `@tbl:id`.

When processing the markdown document, simply add `--filter pandoc-fignos --filter pandoc-tablenos` to the `pandoc` command.